# BeautifulSoup dont take html page in cyrcl

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I ran into a problem that when parsing, the soup checks the same page every time.
I use it in conjunction with selenium. Selenium opens a new link without problems, but the soup only checks the very first one.

The saddest thing is that I used similar constructs in other code with another site and it works as it should.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


keys_list = []

def start_browser(link):
    profile = 'C:\\Users\\Crazy_MoT\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default'
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    try:
        options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={profile}")
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    except:
        print("Connect to profile... Error\n Opening new profile")
        browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        browser.quit()
        #browser.get(link)
        
    browser.get(link)
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    author = soup.find("a", attrs={'data-qa': 'FileViewAuthorBox'}, href=True)
    print(author["href"])

    keywords = soup.find_all("span", class_="_oX66p")
    for keys in keywords:
        keys_list.append(keys.text)
    print(keys_list)


def start(links):
    for link in links:
        start_browser(link)


links = ["https://ru.depositphotos.com/26182475/stock-photo-happy-birthday.html",
         "https://ru.depositphotos.com/39273619/stock-photo-label-with-happy-birthday.html"]
         
start(links)
```

I want to collect information from different pages of the site.
I get information only from the very first page and then it repeats

Comment: are you sure? i get different results

Comment: try printing the url with `print('parsing ', browser.current_url)` after *`browser.get(link)`* to check whether it's going to the right address

Comment: It turns out that the script is written correctly. Because the same scheme in another script for another site worked for me.

Selenium WebDriver is on the right track. I see it when I run the script (the browser is launched explicitly). By all indications, the script should work.

How can I explain my mistake then? Something with Windows or paycharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code works as it should. When checking on other machines, the error did not appear.